# Acrobat XI forms invisible

Tags: acrobat

I am trying to make a form I used FormsCentral For Acrobat, and it looks fine and when I open my pdf in acrobat it looks great but when I open it in a pdf viewer the fields in the form are invisible and the user cannot see where they are supposed to enter the data. They work fine, i.e. when you click on them they can be typed into, but the user can not see where to type.

I want to know how to either put a box around them or to make some sort of contrast.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a viewer other than Adobe Acrobat? Adobe Acrobat will by default highlight any available fields. If it isn't, look for a setting to change that.

If you create a form with Adobe Acrobat Pro, you can double click the fields to get a properties dialog, and there are settings for border and fill color under the 'Appearance' tab. I don't know how FormsCentral is set up, but it may have a similar command.